# Does TFS support multiple pending changelists like Perforce?

Tags: tfs

I am used to working with Perforce and I really like the ability to be able to group checked out files under different pending changelists. For example, if I am working on two bugs at the same time and the changes made for them can be grouped separately.

I am unable to find this functionality in TFS. Is this supported? If no, what is the best practice around it?
I am using VS 2015 Professional with TFS Server 2015.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not supported with pending changelists in TFS for now.

To be a workaround, this is possible using the **Suspend/Resume** feature in Visual Studio 2012 and above. It will allow you to keep multiple shelvesets, associated to multiple workitems. Only problem  is that you can't have all two bugs open at the same time, so you'll **have to check them in one by one**.

[image]

More detail info please refer this link: [Suspend your work and manage your shelvesets](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets)